# Jersey client creation in a REST service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, design-patterns

i am creating a http REST service that consumes other http REST services.

I am using Jersey Client to call other services and i have many doubt about which creation pattern of the http client is the best.

Currently i am using EJB with injection of the client that is a Singleton shared by every methods, but i would like to remove java ee dependency and use Jetty as embedded application server.

I see from [the doc](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/package-summary.html) that Client creation is an expensive operation so i cannot create one every time i need it.

I think about creating 1 in the constructor of every Servlet/Rest class is the simpler solution but i am not sure about the lifecycle of the servlet (if an instance is created for every request, this method is quite the same as the previous)

Or maybe is better to create a Singleton shared by every Servlet/Rest class

Or maybe better a pool of N client.

About this last two solution i need some advice... What do you think it's the better solution?

Thanks

Comment: I am not very satisfied with the current answers, because they explain how to do but the question is more which is the better choice

Answer (score 0):

According to you, there is a `REST Service` deployed in some environment and there is one application, a `client` or `consumer`, which wants to access that service.

If i am writing a normal `Java class` as client using Jersey API, then i will write something lime this :

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

Client client = Client.create(); 
WebResource webResource = client
       .resource("http://localhost:8080/rest/example/employees");

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
               .get(ClientResponse.class);
String result = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Now say you are writing a `servlet`, which does some defined job in you application, also it makes a call to the `REST Service` using client block of code, everytime you access the `servlet` it will create a instance of `com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client` each time.

If you want to avoid this then you can create a initial class that will create an instance of `com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client`, one and only, and make it static and use the same reference where ever you want. `WebResource` should be created as and when required, because you might be interested to call different `URIs`.

I would have followed this approach, if i were in your situation.